# How to use hjkl to navigate menu select in fish shell

Tags: shell, fish

I can't seem to find any information on how to navigate tab completion or how to bind keys in tab completion in fish shell.

This is what I am trying to achieve but in fish shell rather than zsh. [Fish-like argument completion search in ZSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367693/fish-like-argument-completion-search-in-zsh)

Please help...

Comment: You'll probably get more eyes if you ask on stack overflow.

Comment: Are you sure you linked to the question you meant to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab completion pager uses the same keys as the rest of the command-line editor, so to bind <kbd>h</kbd> to move in the pager (and stay as inserting `h` when writing a command) use:

```
bind h 'if commandline --paging-mode; commandline --function backward-char; else; commandline --insert h; end'
```

Similar lines can be added for <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, and <kbd>l</kbd>.

Note, however, that this breaks while the pager is in search mode (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) as there is no way of detecting whether search mode is active (that's probably a missing feature).